# Is it correct: how it works

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I am going to create the next situation, I am working in a web development company...:

> Boss: What are you doing?
>
> Me: I am working with Angular, I developed a simple project to see **how
>   it works**.
>
> Boss: Ok.

Well, I have a question: when I say "**how it works**", is it correct? Or I should say "**how does it work?**" or something like that. Because I am not asking him about Angular, I am telling him an assertion that I am working with it.

I get confused with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. “How it works” is appropriate for an assertion, and “how does it work” is appropriate for a question. You are not asking a question here.

Comment: Ok. Yes, that was my question, I did not know if "How it works" sentence was grammatically correct. Thanks for your reply :)